# How do you add a CDATA section to an XMLDocument object in Actionscript 3?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, cdata

I remember doing it before, so I guess I'm missing something here.
XMLNode's nodeType property only support ELEMENT_NODE and TEXT_NODE, and if I try to add the CDATA section to the XMLNode as a string it get escaped.

```
var node:XMLNode = new XMLNode(3, "<![CDATA[some text and <tags> here]]>");
```

What I get is a TEXT_NODE with the following value:

> &lt ;![CDATA[some text and &lt
>   ;tags&gt ; here]]&gt ;

which isn't even a valid value for a TEXT_NODE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not parse, you may need a backway of doing it.

**Trial one** : add your node content as a string

```
var sometext:String = 'some text and <tags> here';
```

add a blank `XMLNode` to your document and then use xml.replace

```
xml.replace('blanknode','<blanknode><![CDATA[' + sometext + ']]></blanknode>');
```

**Trial two**: return it from a `XML` return type function into the `XMLNode`

**Update**

```
var sometext:String = 'some text and <b>bold</b> here';
        var nodeblank:XMLNode = new XMLNode(1,insert(sometext));
        trace(nodeblank);


        var txt:TextField = new TextField();
        txt.htmlText = nodeblank.nodeName;
        addChild(txt);
```

This shows in the `TextField` -> some text and **bold** here

```
public function insert(s:String):XML {
            var x:XML = new XML("<![CDATA[" + s + "]]>");
            return x;
    }
```

Comment: If I understand correctly you're talking about using the XML class, but this way I'll lose all the XMLDocument and XMLNode functionality won't I?
Can you please elaborate on that "Trail two" solution?

Comment: yip that is correct if you need backwards compatibility with AS2 then 1 would not work.